# Why do we need Box-Muller Transform to generate a Normal distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution

When I search for any implementation of random numbers from Normal Distribution, I find that they are using [the Box-Muller method to implement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/218600/159072) it.

Is there any specific reason for using this specific method?

Why don't I just use the formula for normal distribution and multiply a random value with that to obtain a random value from normal distribution?

Comment: How do you get 'formula for normal distribution' in the first place?

Comment: @StubbornAtom, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function